# Aligning point’s normals to a curve

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I’ve been working to simplify my project I’m having trouble with to smaller bite size chunks. I’ll describe my project briefly below in the hope that if I’m going down the wrong path I can focus in a new direction.

I’ve been successful in applying points to a plane and then adjusting them to my liking. Now I’m trying to do the same thing on a cylinder. I can apply the points and set new positions, but capturing the normal vectors from the source cylinder has been a challenge.

[image]

Any pointers on aligning these point’s normals?

The goal is to take a curved model I have a model and create a random wave-like pattern across the whole surface. I’ve done this before, manually, on “cubed” spheres.  This was easier because the underlying mesh was perfectly distributed. First I need to manipulate these points, then add these points to the original mesh, then smooth the transitions between all the mesh points.

Comment: Hi, welcome to BSE. First hint: you should add images directly into your question and not link them because the link might break in the future. You can easily copy/paste or drag/drop them into your question. Second one: you should always add a sketch/image of your end result how it should look like into your question so that it is clear what you mean. You can describe an image with 1000 words and  and still an image would you tell more details. Third: if you wanna make it easy for the people who help you for free, you should provide a blend file so we have less work. thx

Comment: Hi Chris,  Thanks for the welcome and the pointers. I'll be better!  Regarding point #3, is there a best practice for attaching the blender file?

Answer (score 1):

Points don't have normals, so you have to 'remember' what the Face (or Vertex) Normals were, on the mesh, so those values can be interpolated onto the point-geometry, when it's instantiated. You can do this with 'Capture Attribute':

[image]

### **Edit**

As @Markus von Broady has annoyingly pointed out... I'm as blind as a bat. The Distribute Points on Faces node already stashes Face Normals:

[image]

I'll try to wriggle out of that by saying if you want interpolated vertex (not face) normals, you'd still have to do something like the first suggestion.

Comment: Hmmm  https://i.imgur.com/YDxckKz.png :D

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Grrrrrrr! :D. (see edit).

Comment: This is perfect.  I was able to recreate this and apply it to other more complex curves I'm working on.  I'm going to create a new post for my next challenge and include more pictures of the effect I am going for.

Comment: I was thinking my random value needed to be aligned to the normal.  The offset needs to be aligned and scaled by the random.  Seems obvious now.